# How to insert spacing between my list items?

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to add the space I have between these two blocks:
[image]

My current display is almost correct but it doesn't have the space between the blocks:
[image]

The code is

```
<div class="data-box">   
            <div class="personName"><strong>    
                1. Joey Tempest&nbsp;
             </strong></div> 
        <div class="otherDetails"></div> 

        <table border="0"><tr><td></td><td>Telefon</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>Fax</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>E-post</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Sverige                                           </td><td>Referens</td><td></td></tr>
        </table> 


    </div>  

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="fl10"></div>



        <div class="data-box">   
            <div class="personName"><strong>    
                2. Tone Norum&nbsp;
             </strong></div> 
        <div class="otherDetails"></div> 

        <table border="0"><tr><td></td><td>Telefon</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>Fax</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>E-post</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Sverige                                           </td><td>Referens</td><td></td></tr>
        </table> 


    </div>
```

I can insert just a `<br>` and then a space will appear. Is this a good solution?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, adding `<br />` is not a good solution. 
You should give margin-bottom to your data-box divs:

```
div.data-box{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

If you need the last div not to have a margin, you can also define it.

Here is working fiddle (sorry for lack of desing, you did not specify css code.)
http://jsfiddle.net/DCuKm/1/

Comment: I think the - `:last` in your fiddle should be: `:last-child`.

Comment: Also be aware that if you want it to work in IE6-IE8, you should avoid using `last-child` (see: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).  An cross browser fix is just to add an additional class to the last one e.g. `last` then set the bottom margin to 0 for that.

Comment: @MarkRhodes, you are right. However, last-child is not the topic of this question. Besides, last-child actually do not work, because there is no parent for data-box. One should better use jquery :last selector. I updated the fiddle accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Add margin to your divison.

```
.data-box {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add a bottom margin to the `data-box` divs.

i.e.

```
div.data-box {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

This is generally a better solution than a break as it's more flexible.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/6PZnC/